# Not all child elements trigger parent element click handler in Javascript (not preventDefault issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have parent div - `.parent` - that has 300px height and 200 px width(doesn't matter).

I have a `.child1`,`.child2`, `.child3` elements inside `.parent` div, each of them has content and height/width (this is just for simplicity, there are much more nesting in each of the child). All 3 children elements together occupy entire parent's container height. (e.g. every child has 100px height).

I have a click listener on `.parent` div:

```
 $('.parent').click(function (){
    console.log("Parent div clicked");
 });
```

I noticed that my `.parent` click handler is triggered only if I clicked on `.child3` element. When I am clicking on `child1` or `child2` - the event is not triggered.

What can be possible reasons why the parent click handler works only when clicking on `.child3` and doesn't work when clicking on `.child1`,`.child2`?

I cannot share entire javascript/css of this issue, as there are a lot of it associated with every child and parent elements. I just wanted to get a hint where should I look?

My initial though was that there is some `preventDefault/stopPropagation` associated with `.child1`,`.child2`, which prevents click to be triggered on parent element, however, I didn't find any  `preventDefault` associated with  `.child1` or `.child2`. Also, checked `pointer-events` too.

What else can impact that? Z-index? position:absolute?

***UPDATE:***
I also added click handler on document to see, what is a target when I click on `.child1` or `.child2`. However, even this event is not triggered when I click on `.child1` or `.child2`. It's triggered only if I click on `.child3` (same as for `.parent`).

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  console.log("Document click: " + event);
});
```

Comment: How about simplifying it out to a minimal sample case? Give a few lines of html, a couple of the JS functions like you already did, and that's about it. If it still acts in this way for you, it'll be a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: We don't need the entire javascript/CSS, that's what a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is all about. At least one parent with the child examples and relevant CSS should be enough. Could the child3 possibly be missing a closing tag end, perhaps, which makes the parent fire?

Comment: Did you check `pointer-events` style on the unclickable elements?

Comment: Yeah, checked "pointer-events" too!

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any click handlers on `child1` or `child2`?

Comment: There are click handlers on `child1`/`child2`, however, there is no `preventDefault` on them.

Comment: @WomenWhoCode how about [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)? That would be the one to stop your events bubbling up. Returning `false` from a jQuery click handler will have a similar effect. Do any of the child click handlers `return false`?

Comment: No, I don't see any `stopPropagation/stopImmediatePropagation` or `return false` from any of click handlers